# Replace arbitrary number of spaces with '#' (Awk for >1 spaces)

Tags: regex, awk, find, replace, ls

I'm trying to:

- Taking a file/directory listing, and replacing all spaces >1 (NOT \t) with '#' for all files modified within the last 30 minutes.

Example output of: `find / -mmin -30 -ls`

```
310116371    0 -r--r--r--   1 root     root            0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/wchan
310116373    0 -r--r--r--   1 root     root            0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/schedstat
310116374    0 -r--r--r--   1 root     root            0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/cpuset
310116383    0 -r--r--r--   1 root     root            0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/oom_score
310116384    0 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root            0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/oom_adj
310116382    0 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root            0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/loginuid
310116416    0 -r--------   1 root     root            0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/limits
310116418    0 -r--r--r--   1 root     root            0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/io
```

What I want:

```
310116371#0#-r--r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan 14 0814#/proc/4732/wchan
```

---

Specifically, I want to use {awk, sed, tr} to replace spaces where the amount of space is greater than 1. The only problem is, there is a single space after the timestamp arg for the directory listing...

Is there a computational method which exists today which can to this?

- Log file being parsed consists of ~26k entries
- Output being pasted into an .XLS file

---

What I've tried:

```
find / -mmin -5 -ls |  awk '{gsub(/s+/,"#",$0); print;}'
find / -mmin -5 -ls |  awk '{gsub(/[' ']+/,"#")}1'
find / -mmin -5 -ls |  awk '{gsub(/["  "]+/,"#")}1'
find / -mmin -5 -ls | sed "s/^ *//;s/ *$//;s/ \{1,\}/#/g"
find / -mmin -5 -ls |  awk -D '{gsub([ +],"#",$0); print;}' 
find / -mmin -5 -ls |  awk '{gsub(/\t/,"#",$0); print;}'
```

---

The problem:
- The output of `find / -mmin -5 -ls` is not {tab, comma} delimited by default

---

Any suggestions about where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using `find -printf ...` instead of `find -ls` so you don't need to try to parse the find output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick for me `awk 'gsub(/\s+/,"#")'`:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/\s+/,"#")' file
310116371#0#-r--r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan#14#0814#/proc/4732/wchan
310116373#0#-r--r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan#14#0814#/proc/4732/schedstat
310116374#0#-r--r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan#14#0814#/proc/4732/cpuset
310116383#0#-r--r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan#14#0814#/proc/4732/oom_score
310116384#0#-rw-r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan#14#0814#/proc/4732/oom_adj
310116382#0#-rw-r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan#14#0814#/proc/4732/loginuid
310116416#0#-r--------#1#root#root#0#Jan#14#0814#/proc/4732/limits
310116418#0#-r--r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan#14#0814#/proc/4732/io
```

Or `awk 'gsub(/\s{2,}/,"#")'` for:

> Specifically, I want to use {awk, sed, tr} to replace spaces where the
>   amount of space is greater than 1 (so, I can preserve the timestamp
>   arg)

```
$ awk 'gsub(/\s{2,}/,"#")' file
310116371#0 -r--r--r--#1 root#root#0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/wchan
310116373#0 -r--r--r--#1 root#root#0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/schedstat
310116374#0 -r--r--r--#1 root#root#0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/cpuset
310116383#0 -r--r--r--#1 root#root#0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/oom_score
310116384#0 -rw-r--r--#1 root#root#0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/oom_adj
310116382#0 -rw-r--r--#1 root#root#0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/loginuid
310116416#0 -r--------#1 root#root#0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/limits
310116418#0 -r--r--r--#1 root#root#0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/io

# Single spacing
$ awk 'gsub(/\s{2,}/," ")' file
310116371 0 -r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/wchan
310116373 0 -r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/schedstat
310116374 0 -r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/cpuset
310116383 0 -r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/oom_score
310116384 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/oom_adj
310116382 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/loginuid
310116416 0 -r-------- 1 root root 0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/limits
310116418 0 -r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/io
```

**Edit:**

How about just setting the `OFS` variable:

```
# Hash seperated
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="#"}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11}' file
310116371#0#-r--r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan#14#0814#/proc/4732/wchan
310116373#0#-r--r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan#14#0814#/proc/4732/schedstat
310116374#0#-r--r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan#14#0814#/proc/4732/cpuset
310116383#0#-r--r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan#14#0814#/proc/4732/oom_score
310116384#0#-rw-r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan#14#0814#/proc/4732/oom_adj
310116382#0#-rw-r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan#14#0814#/proc/4732/loginuid
310116416#0#-r--------#1#root#root#0#Jan#14#0814#/proc/4732/limits
310116418#0#-r--r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan#14#0814#/proc/4732/io

# Hash sperated accounting for the spaces in the date
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="#"}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8" "$9" "$10,$11}' file
310116371#0#-r--r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan 14 0814#/proc/4732/wchan
310116373#0#-r--r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan 14 0814#/proc/4732/schedstat
310116374#0#-r--r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan 14 0814#/proc/4732/cpuset
310116383#0#-r--r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan 14 0814#/proc/4732/oom_score
310116384#0#-rw-r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan 14 0814#/proc/4732/oom_adj
310116382#0#-rw-r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan 14 0814#/proc/4732/loginuid
310116416#0#-r--------#1#root#root#0#Jan 14 0814#/proc/4732/limits
310116418#0#-r--r--r--#1#root#root#0#Jan 14 0814#/proc/4732/io

# Single space sperated 
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=" "}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11}' file
310116371 0 -r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/wchan
310116373 0 -r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/schedstat
310116374 0 -r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/cpuset
310116383 0 -r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/oom_score
310116384 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/oom_adj
310116382 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/loginuid
310116416 0 -r-------- 1 root root 0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/limits
310116418 0 -r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 14 0814 /proc/4732/io
```

Comment: For me, that replaces the 's' character with '#' - GNU Awk v.3.1.5 (cannot upgrade, not my machine)

Comment: Sorry sudo_O, I failed you and the community - I didn't realize that there was only a single space after the timestamp arg. Editing my question...is there a feasible solution that exists today?

Comment: OFS seems like a desirable option, but what about the requirement for a '#' delimeter? Would I awk the awk?

Comment: @TylerJFisher yes see my edit I believe the second output is what you want, uses the output separator field variable.

Comment: The 2nd edit does not make use of the '#" delimeter, it removes spaces which is nice...but that doesn't help. :/

Comment: @TylerJFisher my edit contains 3 new scripts of which the second is what you required I believe, the one commented `# Hash sperated accounting for the spaces in the date`

Comment: Solution 5 doesn't preserve the timestamp, it attempts to re-create it but would fail to do so if the day number had 1 digit instead of 2, e.g. it would convert `Jan  4 0814` (2 spaces between Jan and 4) to `Jan 4 0814` (1 space between Jan and 4).